# Sending Arrow Keys to Popen

Tags: python, popen

I know that it's possible to send printable input to `subprocess`es by `write`ing to their `stdin`

```
from subprocess import, Popen, PIPE
proc = Popen([command, goes, here], stdin=PIPE)
proc.stdin.write("m")
```

How would I go about sending input such as arrow key presses, space, return, or backspace?

Comment: Is there a specific command you are trying to run?

Comment: @NathanVillaescusa - Specifically, I'm trying to run `omxplayer` as a subprocess and send it Left/Right/Up/Down arrows in order to seek. The rest of its interactive commands use printable characters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found someone who was trying to solve the opposite problem, create a program that could recognize the arrow keys: [Recognizing arrow keys with stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130048/recognizing-arrow-keys-with-stdin)

I also found
http://compgroups.net/comp.unix.programmer/how-to-send-up-arrow-key-to-popen-child/537480
which says:

```
"\x1B[A" for up
"\x1B[B" for down
```

So if \x1B is the escape character than you just append [A for up, [B for down, [C for right and [D for left and so on.

Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_sequences for a list of the different codes.

Comment: Yup, that did it. Out of curiosity, what did you search for? I came up empty after about 20 minutes of assorted googling for things like `python Popen send arrow keys`.

Comment: I searched for "python handle stdin arrow keys" which led me to the stack overflow question and then "popen ansi escape" which led me to the other link.

Answer (score -1):

Try [pyautogui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48449895/how-to-pass-a-keystroke-alttab-using-popen-communicate-on-linux/48455097#48455097) library. For example:

```
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')  # ctrl-c to copy
pyautogui.press('enter')  # press the Enter key
```

More examples in the library webpage.
For me it worked - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48449895/how-to-pass-a-keystroke-alttab-using-popen-communicate-on-linux/48455097#48455097).