# Sending an arrow key with fprintf

Tags: c, linux, special-characters, ipc, popen

I'm testing out pipes and have hit a little road block.

I want to be able to simulate pressing the right arrow key through a file pointer opened by popen.  The file pointer opens a display program on a different terminal, much like a projector.  I would like to send a signal to advance the next image (the right arrow key).

How do I go about sending this signal?  I realize this will be specific to my computer (BOIS/keyboard setup), but I'm not looking for this to be portable in anyway.

It seems from my trials, everything I send via fprintf is interpreted as readable characters rather than special codes.

The slideshow program cannot be changed, so that isn't an option.  Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can try with `fwrite()` instead of `fprintf()` but I am not sure if it will work.

Comment: Pipes probably will not get where you want to go - the receiving program has to accept that style of input.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Is there alternative?  I'm open to anything at this point.

Comment: To answer, we need more info, for example (a) what type of terminal, e.g., text or GUI, (b) are you trying to automate something or just control it.

Comment: @ThomasDickey (a) text, (b) Just control i.  I don't care about a response.

Comment: You may try sending ANSI escape sequences (cursor back/forward)... but I think your chances in succeeding are pretty slim.

Comment: Perhaps the [expect](http://www2.tcl.tk/16157) program.

Comment: [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755968/sending-arrow-keys-to-popen?rq=1) claims to lead to something useful.  If so, one of the pitfalls is that you probably have to do frequent fflush's to make it work.

Comment: @ThomasDickey That last link was what I needed.  This is perfect. ty.  Post it as an answer, and I'll select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possibilities come to mind:

- The expect program can be used to control terminal applications.  Its wiki shows [An example wherein Expect controls a pager](http://www2.tcl.tk/16157).
- On the other hand, the question *[Sending Arrow Keys to Popen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755968/sending-arrow-keys-to-popen?rq=1)*
  claims to lead to something useful. In particular, note the accepted answer, pointing to *[How to send UP arrow key to popen child](http://compgroups.net/comp.unix.programmer/how-to-send-up-arrow-key-to-popen-child/537480)*, which sends the literal escape sequence for the arrow key via the pipe.

From the comments, that appears to be what was requested.  Arrow (cursor) key escape sequences are well-standardized, as shown in

- [Bash Prompt HOWTO: Chapter 6. ANSI Escape Sequences: Colours and Cursor Movement](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html)
- [VT100.net: VT100 User Guide: Chapter 3. Programmer Information](http://www.vt100.net/docs/vt100-ug/chapter3.html#CUF), e.g., `CUF` (cursor forward).

If that works for you, one of the pitfalls is that you probably have to do frequent `fflush`'s to make it work.

Comment: I spoke too soon, this solution didn't work in the final environment, just in my initial test environment.