# How to pass a keystroke (ALT+TAB) using Popen.communicate (on Linux)?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, subprocess, raspbian

I have two images open in a full-screen mode on my Raspberry Pi (using ristretto image viewer). When certain conditions are met, I need to pass an ALT+TAB keystroke combination to display the other one. I am trying to use Popen.communicate, but I don't know how to pass a key combination like ALT+TAB).
Does anyone have any ideas?

What I need is something like below (replacing "ALT+TAB" with a working code):

```
s = Popen(['ristretto', '-f', 'my.gif' ,'&'],stdin=PIPE)
if my_condition:
    s.communicate("ALT+TAB")
```

I heard about [SendKeys](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SendKeys) package, but it works only for Windows...

Thanks, Michal

Comment: There is a package called **atspi** that simulates keystrokes. Google it's documentation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably can't do exactly what your question says - pass keystrokes using Popen. You can send bytes to the `stdin` of the process you've opened, but it's almost certainly not looking there for them. Keyboard events are different from data coming on `stdin`.

The [pyautogui library](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui) library could be useful for this purpose, however. Once it's installed, you could launch your viewer with `Popen`, as you've done, and then use

```
pyautogui.hotkey('alt', 'tab')
```

To send alt+tab to the foreground application. You may need to add a short delay to make sure ristretto has finished launching before sending the keys. See [pyautogui's keyboard documentation](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html) for more details about how to use it.