# ord() to catch Arrow Key press on Linux and Mac

Tags: python, linux, macos, key-bindings, keycode

How do I use ord() to catch an arrow key press in Mac and Linux? I know you can use the msvcrt in Windows. They don't have a character associated with them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22397289/finding-the-values-of-the-arrow-keys-in-python-why-are-they-triples

Comment: I specifically need to use ord() ...

Comment: It's not possible using ord. Ord returns an unicode value of a character, the arrow keys don't have any character bound to them.

Comment: But they do ... as the answer below indicates... it just happens to be more than one character. And it seems to be a part of a special type of character list, not part of ASCII

Comment: Use 8456 or wasd instead of the arrow keys. And the code below isn't working for me.

Comment: Well I guess you could use  wasd ... I was asked to get arrow keys working so...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the Values of the Arrow Keys in Python: Why are they triples?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22397289/608639)

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about in the console?

I have a hacky solution if you want to avoid msvcrt.

```
    value = raw_input("Hit left arrow key then ENTER: ")
    print ord(value[0]), ord(value[1]), ord(value[2])
    if ord(value[0]) == 27 and ord(value[1]) == 91 and ord(value[2]) == 68:
        print "You hit the left key!"
    elif ord(value[0]) == 27 and ord(value[1]) == 91 and ord(value[2]) == 67:
        print "You hit the right key!"
```

This is written to illustrate how it's done. You can easily condense this into a more consice system depending on what you need. You can use ord -- just need to remember that it's a multi-character string that you need to analyze character by character.

Comment: Is there a way that I can avoid hitting the enter key? That would like solve all of the issues I'm having right now. I am actually using this for a GUI that I am making with wxPython, but the thing they use to catch a keypress doesn't work on a Mac....soooo this is me trying to do it manually. That's why I need to avoid hitting the enter key since I can't really be using the terminal or console :((( But you deserve upvote for this nice workaround anyway :)

Comment: Do you get a keyCode at all for pressing those keys in your program? Or does it just do nothing when you press those keys?

Comment: Did you post the question for wxPython? Cause the idea that NO event is triggered for a EVT_KEY_DOWN on the arrow keys is problematic. You should definitely consider testing it on other systems to eliminate some variables from the situation.

Comment: I didn't post it yet no ... I guess I will