# Python raw input with arrows

Tags: python, linux, input, console

How can I allow the arrows in `raw_input()`?

There is a better way?

When I write and I use the left arrow, `^[[D` appears.

I am using Linux.

Comment: Using arrow keys as input in Python is described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22397289/finding-the-values-of-the-arrow-keys-in-python-why-are-they-triples).

Comment: @MattDMo I don't really think this a duplicate.   The linked question asks about _why_ there are 3 special letters printed. The question here is, _how_ to make the arrow keys move the cursor as expected.

Answer (score 3):

If you are Windows, the cursor keys work normally to allow editing of your input. On Linux, I find that I need to `import readline` to get the input editing module.

If you Google for "python readline" you will get many more hits and suggestions on enhanced editing, tab completion, etc.

Comment: Just importing readline and doing nothing else fixes the arrow keys.  I find this to be a little bit of witchcraft

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

`myinput = raw_input("Enter your input ->")`

I am using windows , it works fine. Don't have a linux to simulate.

Also, why are you pressing arrow keys? Is it a need for program?
You can simply make arrow using a `dash` and `greater than` keys.

Comment: I don't think the OP is trying to enter an arrow, I think they are trying to use the cursor arrows to move left and right in the input to edit the input before pressing return.

Comment: In that case I think OP may be having terminal settings issue if he is trying to go left or right within `input` window.  `stty sane` , followed by `export TERM=linux` may resolve the issue and also need to add `linux` tag to this question.