# Python MacOS Terminal: Keyboard Arrow keys in raw_input()

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, terminal, keyboard

Using Python 2.7, I'd like my program to accept Keyboard Arrow Keys – e.g. <kbd>↑</kbd> while inputting into MacOS Terminal.

Pressing <kbd>↑</kbd> in Terminal outputs `^[[A` in it, so I've assumed this is the escape key sequence.

However, pressing the <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>RETURN</kbd> at the `raw_input()` prompt doesn't seem to produce a string that can then be conditioned:

```
string = raw_input('Press ↑ Key: ')

if string == '^[[A':
    print '↑'         # This doesn't happen.
```

How can this be done?

Note that I'm not trying to input whatever the previous line was in the shell (I think this is was `import readline` manages). I just want to detect that an arrow key on the keyboard was entered somehow.

Comment: Obligatory notice that Python 2.7 [is officially no longer supported](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/), and will no longer be receiving bug fixes, security updates, or changes of any kind. If at all possible, migrate to Python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried something like:

```
% cat test.py
char = raw_input()
print("\nInput char is [%s]." % char)
% python a.py
^[[A
           ].
```

It blanked out the "\Input char is [" part of the print statement.
It appears that raw_input() does not receive escaped characters. The terminal program is catching the escaped keystrokes and using it to manipulate the screen. You will have to use a lower level program to catch these characters. 
Check out if [Finding the Values of the Arrow Keys in Python: Why are they triples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22397289/finding-the-values-of-the-arrow-keys-in-python-why-are-they-triples) help on how to get these keystrokes.

From the currently [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22398481/4909923):

> ```
>     if k=='\x1b[A':
>             print "up"
>     elif k=='\x1b[B':
>             print "down"
>     elif k=='\x1b[C':
>             print "right"
>     elif k=='\x1b[D':
>             print "left"
>     else:
>             print "not an arrow key!"
> ```

Comment: Thanks – the suggested escape code strings in the accepted answer works. E.g. `'\x1b[A'` is `↑`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `pynput.keyboard.Listener`, which allows you to [monitor the keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/) and to take different actions depending on the key that is pressed. It is available for Python 2.7.

This example is a good way to get started:

```
from pynput import keyboard

def on_press(key):
    try:
        print('alphanumeric key {0} pressed'.format(
            key.char))
    except AttributeError:
        print('special key {0} pressed'.format(
            key))

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} released'.format(
        key))
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

# Collect events until released
with keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()

# ...or, in a non-blocking fashion:
listener = keyboard.Listener(
    on_press=on_press,
    on_release=on_release)
listener.start()
```